# 250 GB SSD for programming cheaper than ~£100?

Tags: ssd, performance

What would you recommend to choose? I was thinking about Samsung 850 Pro and Crucial MX200 but every suggestion would be appreciated. 250GB seems to be fine for me (I have one another 1TB HDD).

My expectations:

- sequential read > 300 MB/s
- sequential write > 150 MB/s
- low access times
- improve compile time
- improve IDE & Git performance

I rarely do video edit. It is mainly about reducing the compile cycle time and work smoothly on multiple files simultaneously.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is more of a poll, in that answers are really going to be a "yes" or a "no". This question is very opinion based and subjective, which is not reflective of the sites quality standards.

Comment: Related Meat Post: http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/199/how-to-deal-with-yes-or-no-questions

Comment: I'm voting to leave this question open. Although I agree the content of the meta post, I disagree to apply rules retroactively. On other SE sites there is a tag named "historical" for such content, and this should be done here as well.

Comment: @peterh this site is still in closed beta. A "historical" perspective on a question which during the closed beta doesn't fit does not make sense at all.

Comment: The question has been changed. I would not narrow the choice.

Comment: @enderland Well, you have right. :-) But finally the op changed the question to a more acceptable form.

Comment: The Intel 730 series SSDs are great, but more expensive than samsung ones. Buy one if you are willing to splurge, as they are the best on the market

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've got the 256gb variant of the Samsung 850 **Pro** and running a few tests would be quite enlightening. Improving compile time may also depend on processor so... it depends on your options. Likewise with IDE & Git performance. That said, I upgraded from an 840 (which I can't find the benchmarks for, its on my laptop at the moment) and it was a significant improvement. Enough yammering.
Science!

BIOS time (boot time) is 15 seconds according to Windows. My system is a bit of a mess and I could probably remove things to speed it up more :)

This is a drive I've been using as a boot drive. Optimised for performance in Samsung Disk Magician, though kept fairly empty, since bulk storage is another drive.

HD Tune benchmarks

[image]

I believe these numbers exceed your requirements.

Crystal Disk Mark Benchmarks with what I believe is the default settings.

[image]

Few other nice things about this? ***[10 year warranty](http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/minisite/SSD/global/html/support/warranty.html)***, and its MLC rather than TLC, which means better endurance and speed.

Answer (score 2):

SDDs are quite conspicuous when it comes to quality and performance. Capacity, read/write times are made very clear so you can buy what you need. Any further optimisation will come down to your OS, and they're usually pretty good. 250 GB is more than I need for programming but if you think you need that then go for it. Depending on the size of the project, read write times are usually less of an issue since your OS will cache it anyway. This prevents constant read writes to your SSD and makes use of faster cache storage eg. RAM. If your project size is larger than the capacity of RAM your OS is dedicating to your project then it can become important. However if you're constantly recompiling entire large projects, you probably don't need to be and should adapt your programming environment.

Both of those SDDs offer 535MB MB/s write and 540MB/s / 370MB/s read which is more than you're asking for.

Comment: Do controllers in SSDs vary so much? How it relates to the durability?

Answer (score 0):

Generally the performance of brand name SSD's will meet all your criteria and be comparable from an end users perspective, the Samsung 850 EVO has been well received and can be had for £67 currently on [Amazon](http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00P736UEU/?tag=hotukdealsnl-21).